# How to select All JTextFields and get their text-Java

Tags: java

Lets say we have a class with a lot of JTextFields like the following:

```
public class MultipleFields{

 JTextField a=new JTextField();
 JTextField b=new JTextField();
 JTextField c=new JTextField();

  //There are many more jtextfields in my actual code 
 public void getTextFromFields(){
    //implementation code goes here
   }

}
```

Is there any api,library or something i could use to get the text from all JTextFields(Or do something else with all these jtextfields?)

Comment: `Is there any api,library or something` - no. Why do you have so many text fields? If you have "rows" of data, then you should have arrays of data and iterate over the array. Or the other approach is to use a Swing component like a `JTable` which has an API to display rows of data. If you have many individual text fields then each text field should have a descriptive name so people know how the text field is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<JTextField>` or an array.

```
public class MultipleFields {
    JTextField textFields = new JTextField[700];

    public MultipleFields() {
        for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; ++i) {
            textFields[i] = new JTextField();
        }
    }

    public String allTexts() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; ++i) {
            sb.append(i).append(": ").append(textFields[i].getText().append(EOL);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```